# Improve performance when computing adjusted p-values with tbl_summary or tbl_uvregression from {gtsummary}

Tags: r, performance, cpu-usage, gtsummary

I am using `tbl_uvregression` (or `tbl_summary`) from `{gtsummary}` with a relatively small dataframe (200 rows, 800 columns).

When computing multiple univariate regression with adjusted p-value:

```
tbl_uvregression(df, method=coxph, y = Surv(time = survival_time, event = status),
  exponentiate = TRUE) %>% add_q()
```

or some intergroup comparisons with adjusted p-value:

```
tbl_summary(data = df, by = group, missing = "no") %>% add_p() %>% add_q(method = "fdr") %>% sort_p
```

it takes **so much time (more than 10 minutes)**. I was wondering if this could be improved because my CPU is only slightly used (globally up to 20%) and the RAM is not used at all.
**Is it possible to make it faster by using more CPUs and/or RAM?**

[image: CPU usage]

My computer is a Dell XPS (9570) with 16 Gb RAM and i7-8750H (6 cores, 12 threads, 2.2 Ghz) intel CPU, running on Windows 10. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It's likely that the time intensive part is the confidence interval calculation. If you don't need the CI, then it's best not to include it. Another way to improve computation is to estimate the models outside of `tbl_uvregression()` using parallel computing methods (e.g. futures or one of the many other pkgs to assist with this). Once you have the models, use `tbl_regression()` to summarize each individually, and finally stack them with `tbl_stack()`.

Comment: You're building 798 models here. While 200 obs is not huge it is still a huge amount of work for your machine

Comment: I agree with the fact it is a huge amount of work, but yet, i don't understand why my CPU is not pushed harder (never becoming hot, never going really loud with fans spinning fast...). What is the purpose of getting 6 cores/12 thread if only a few can be used...